# fastest way to find number of digits in number

Tags: decimal-expansion

What's the fastest way to determine the number of digits in a number?

Would it be like so:

```
const val = 10030504;
const numOfDigits = math.floor(math.divide(val, 10));
```

or perhaps faster to just convert to a string a get a length:

```
const s = String(val);
const numOfDigits = s.slice(0, s.indexOf('.')).length;
```

using string manipulations feels wrong.

Comment: if someone could add the tag `base-10` that'd be great..

Comment: This is not a math question as it is dependent on the computer and language used.  I think the first does not work.  Wouldn't it return $1003050?$  Whether a string convert is faster or slower than a log function is definitely not math.

Comment: Yeah you're right, so I guess the mathy part of the OP is how to do it without string manipulation - thanks

Comment: If you search for number of digits on this site you will find the formula based on rounding the base 10 log.

Comment: The logarithm formula might fail in the case of a number very near a power of ten and limited precision. Modern tools can store huge numbers and then, the number of digits can simply be counted.

Comment: If you want to use math, the number of digits of $x$ is : 
$$\lfloor \log(x) \rfloor + 1$$
Imagine you want the number of digits of $2^{1000}$.

Comment: @Essaidi yeah a string implementation seems faster sadly

Comment: I don't see why the question got a downvote, I like this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments discuss the (software) vulnerability to rounding errors of taking logarithms, base $10$.

Generally, programming languages such as Java, c, or Python, provide BigInteger facilities for just such a situation (i.e. when rounding errors must be avoided).  Presumably, positive integers as large as $(10)^{(1000)}$ are routinely handled.

So, you can set the corresponding number to an object $A$ of the BigInteger class.  Then, you can create a 2nd BigInteger object $B = 10.$

You can then determine exactly whether $B > A$.  If not, multiply $B = B \times 10,$ and re-check whether $B > A$. Assuming that $A < (10)^{(1000)}$, your (very simple) program should routinely find the smallest value of $B$, using this algorithm, such that $B > A$.

Assuming that you maintain a counter $I1$, then if $(10)^{(I1)}$ is the smallest value of $B$ such that $B > A$, then $A$ has exactly $I1$ digits.